# Creating a colour coded plot for specific conditions (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a plot based on certain parameters. I want to split a scatter plot into two colours based on another data set, and then the transparency based on a further data set. So I have a set of x coordinates, y coordinates, strength of coordinates and type.
E.g.

```
xcoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
ycoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
strength = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8]
type = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']
```

I've managed to plot the data with the transparency, but I would like to change the colours of the points based on a 4th set of data. I.e. if apple then red, and if banana then blue.

So far I have this code:

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(xcoord, ycoord, c=strength, cmap='PuRd', s=10, label='time 0')
plt.show()
```

Which works, but I'm not sure how to add the colour coding in addition to this. I'm pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
# transform data format to:
# [[xcoord, ycoord, strength, types(color)]
#  [xcoord, ycoord, strength, types(color)]
#                 ...
#                 ...
#  [xcoord, ycoord, strength, types(color)]]

xcoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
ycoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
strength = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8]
types = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']
types = map(lambda x: 'green' if x == 'banana' else 'blue', types)
data = list(zip(xcoord,ycoord,strength,types)) 

# Then plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")

for point in data:
    ax.scatter3D(point[0], point[1], point[2], color = point[3])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to obtain the required result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

xcoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
ycoord = [1,2,3,4,5]
strength = [0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8]
types = ['apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana']

for i in range(5):
    if(types[i]=='apple'):
        colour = 'r'
    else:
        colour = 'y'
    pl.scatter(xcoord[i], ycoord[i], color=colour, alpha=strength[i])
pl.show()
```

matplotlib.pyplot.scatter() simply keeps on adding data in your graph and shows all the data once matplotlib.pyplot.show() is called.

As a beginner, even I didn't knew this :P

Comment: Would it be possible to make this work when the number of values are unknown? As my real data sets have 1000s of values

Comment: Make line 8 as: for i in range(len(xcoord)): . This will solve your issue. If you want detailed explaination, then check out https://stackabuse.com/python-get-number-of-elements-in-a-list/